# Return value as optional with previous condition

Tags: swift, option-type, syntactic-sugar

Considering the following code example which checks whether two rects intersects and returns their intersection rectangle as an optional value:

```
func intersectRect(rect: CGRect, other: CGRect) -> CGRect?
{
    let result = CGRectIntersection(rect, other)
    return CGRectIsNull(result) ? nil : result
}
```

I use this helper several times, usually with `switch`, e.g.

```
switch (intersectRect(rectA, other: rectB), intersectRect(rectA, other: rectC))
{
    case (.Some(let rX), .None(let rY)): doA()
    case (.None(let rX), .Some(let rY)): doB()
    default: doC()
}
```

Question: could this be *even* shorter, i.e. directly check the intersection rectangle without using the helper and return the result if it is not a null-rectangle?

Comment: How short would you like to have it and for what reason? I know that people can write a complex program in one line, but only them are able to read and understand it. Is that your desire?

Comment: It is more out of curiosity, because I like to use the switch syntax in order to remove some (large) `if`/`else if` statements. And since most of e.g. CGGeometry does not use optionals as return values I'd have to create wrappers for them. However, if readability suffers it's clearly not an option for me as I like writing readable code.

Comment: From my (limited) Swift experience your code just looks fine. I would not wonder if Apple decides to adapt their CG libs to return optionals as well.